# How to create a udp-based message broker service

Tags: hadoop, udp, messaging

I want to create a udp-based message broker service.
I have a few dozens of sources, each transmiting at different rates, part of them streaming and part of them forward the data in batch.
I want all the data to go to one destination - a Cloudera Hadoop cluster (using RedHat 6.6 OS), that will use Kafka/Flume as it's message broker.

I need to create the inbetween message broker service. It has to be robust and fault tollerant. It can receive the data from the sources using any protocol, but it has to forward the messages using UDP (or any one-way protocol, no ACK/SYN or any other respond allowed). 
For that reason it has to use a PUSH mechanism, and the data cannot be pulled by the Hadoop cluster.
As much as i know Kafka and Flume - they use TCP to forward messages. I found "udp-kafka-bridge" and "flume-udp-source", but I do not have any experience with them.

The message broker has to be robust and fault tollerant. It has to be able to deal with changing rates of incoming data, and also preferred to be Near Real Time broker.

Do you have any recommendation for tools/architecture I should use?

thank you!